# What is the bold part an example of?

Tags: reference

What does the bold part refer to? Is it an example for the "bottom-up" fake news?

> as philosophers trained in the art of dialectics are wont to remind
>   us, sometimes quantitative changes really can lead to qualitative
>   transformations: dial up the degree of mendacity and the amount of
>   misinformation in circulation, and the public sphere may undergo an
>   irreversible change for the worse. Is that what motivates worries
>   about "fake news", whether state-sanctioned or "bottom-up" -- **as in
>   the many conspiracy theories that have bubbled up in recent years**?

Comment: The entire final sentence is ungrammatical. It has the following construction: *Is that what motivates (whether—as in?* There is an *opening* comma, setting off nonrestrictive information, but no *closing* comma—and no termination to the sentence before the question mark. Is **that what motivates worries about "fake news**" ***what***? There is no actual question. Since the sentence is ungrammatical, it's not really possible to analyze its component.

Answer (score 1):

The part of the sentence that you've bolded uses the phrase "**as in**" to draw a comparison, in this case noting similarity of the apparent "bottom-up" source of conspiracy theories. The things that are being noted as similar are "fake news" conspiracies specifically and, in general, "the many conspiracy theories that have bubbled up in recent years". "**As in**" could be replaced by "**similar to**" or "**like**".

Comment: So it says "bottom up fake-news like in ..." not "government-sanctioned and bottom up fake news like in ..."?

Comment: It's a little ambiguous from this little snippet, but it seems to me that both "state-sanctioned" and "bottom-up" modify "worries" and not "fake news". I believe they refer to the source of the conspiracies, not what the conspiracies are about.

Comment: Can you please make your view clear about what exactly is meant to be before "as in": ... as in the many conspiracy theories that have bubbled up in recent years. What should be put instead of dots?

Comment: Simply another comma, just after the closing quotation mark with no space, instead of the double hyphens would complete the normal formatting of a parenthetical phrase.

Comment: As far as I know, it's not strictly incorrect to use mismatched symbols to wrap a parenthetical phrase, but I feel it's better to avoid confusion like that which inspired your question. :)